# Layers on Google Maps Engine API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, layer

I have three layers that I would like to show up on my map, but none of them are showing up. Is there something wrong with my initialize() function? I've made all the correct declarations within the script tag, so I don't know where else the problem would be.

```
function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng (37.80, -122.27);

var mapOptions = 
{    
zoom: 13,
zoomControl: true, 
mapTypeControl: false,
panControl: false,    
center: latlng,    
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
};


var image = 'css-js/images/hospitalicon-24.png';

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),      mapOptions);

//Fire Stations
var mapsEngineLayer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
  layerId: '08042600090929941501-16143158689603361093',
  map: map
});
//Hospitals
var mapsEngineLayer1 = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
  layerId: '08042600090929941501-08112974690991164587',
  map: map
});

//Police Stations
var mapsEngineLayer2 = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
  layerId: '08042600090929941501-11613121305523030954',
  map: map
});
```

}

Comment: Have you [configured your layers for API access](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mapsenginelayers#configuring_api_access_to_your_layers)? [Making data public](https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/3164737?hl=en&ref_topic=3290470)

Comment: yes what you see above is what I have, and the layerId is present and i changed the settings to public (but still the layers do not show up)

Comment: [works for me now](http://jsfiddle.net/n8Sbd/)